Nextjs website slows down after a week and nginx restarts fix it
I am using next 14 and nginx as a reverse proxy hosted in aws ubuntu ec2. I am using pm2 for process management.
The website works normally, but after a certain time (mostly around a week), it becomes slow and stuck on a loading screen (mostly in loading.tsx loading). Restarting the server with pm2 also doesn't work. The only way to make the website work again is to restart Nginx, and it starts working normally. I have tried various suggestions, but none of them seem to work.
The main thing is that I am unable to figure out which one is causing the issue, Next.js or Nginx.
I have updated my nginx sites-available config.
upstream backend_service {
    server 127.0.0.1:3001;
    keepalive 32; 
}

upstream prod_backend {
    server prod-backend.rb.ai;
    keepalive 32;  # Reuse connections for better performance
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name testing.com www.testing.com;

    # Enable Gzip compression for this site
    gzip on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    # Health Check Endpoint
    location /health {
        return 200 'Healthy';
        add_header Content-Type text/plain;
    }

    # Handle requests for /bm-main... it is to redirect request to backend url
    location /bm-main {
        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'https://testing.com' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range,Authorization' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 86400;
            add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
            add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain';
            return 204;
        }

        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'https://testing.com' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range,Authorization' always;

        proxy_pass https://prod-backend.rb.ai/bm-main;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_connect_timeout 60s;
        proxy_send_timeout 60s;
        proxy_read_timeout 60s;
        proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_502 http_503 http_504;
    }

    # Default Route (For all other requests)
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend_service;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_connect_timeout 60s;
        proxy_send_timeout 60s;
        proxy_read_timeout 60s;
        proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_502 http_503 http_504;
    }
}


i have also updated my pm2 config of ecosystem.config.js
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: 'testing', // Name of the project
      cwd: '/var/www/testing-nextjs', // Path to your Next.js project folder
      script: 'yarn', // Use Yarn to run the app
      args: 'start', // The Yarn start script for Next.js
      instances: 'max', // Use as many CPU cores as available for scaling
      exec_mode: 'cluster', // Enable clustering mode to distribute load
      watch: false, // Disable watching files for changes in production (performance optimization)
      autorestart: true, // Automatically restart if the app crashes
      max_memory_restart: '1G', // Restart the app if it exceeds 1GB of memory usage
      env: {
        NODE_ENV: 'production', // Set environment to production
        PORT: 3001 // The port your Next.js app will run on
      },
      log_date_format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z', // Format for log timestamps
      error_file: '/var/www//logs/error.log', // Path for error logs
      out_file: '/var/www/logs/out.log', // Path for output logs
    }
  ]
};


I have updated nginx and pm2 in the hope of solving the issue but it didn't solve the issue.
Also when this error occurs i tested both nextjs and backend (written in springboot) in local server and both worked perfectly. I also checked logs but no clue what to look for. It would be great if i know a way to figure out whats causing this.

Try to ask this at [SF] rather than [SO].
